# Select object by data attribute

Tags: jquery

How to select a object by data? I've found many examples but none of them seens work for me:

```
$('div').data('name', 'foo');
```

I've tried:

```
$('div').find('[data-name]="foo"').hide();
$('div[data-name]="foo"').hide();
$('div[name]="foo"').hide();
```

any idea?

Comment: What does your actual html look like?

Comment: Using the `.data()` function *doesn't* add or update the associated `data-*` attribute on the element(s), so using the attribute-equals selector won't work.

Comment: `$("div[data-name]='foo'").hide();` should work unless you have stored the data some other way? I copy of the HTML would help

Comment: why not use `.attr` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `filter()`:

```
var $div = $('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('name') === 'foo'; 
});
$div.hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
$('div[data-name=foo]').hide()
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attr` instead:

```
$('div').attr('data-name', 'foo');
$('div[data-name="foo"]').hide();
```

[This article](http://lookfirst.com/2011/12/dont-use-jquery-data-method-use-attr.html) might be interesting to take a look at.